# shutdown -m \\computer only shows usage?

Tags: cmd, command, prompt, shutdown

It might be some dumb mistake, but I'm still a freshman in CS, learning about all these stuff.
At work, shutting down computers is an usual task, so I've been trying to do it remotely, but whenever I try to use this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>shutdown -m \\[computer name] -c "This computer will shutdown momentarily. Please wait." -t 10
```

It simply shows the usage menu for the shutdown command, without any action. I've checked several times using `net view` and the computer chosen is indeed in the network.

Comment: one of the following parameters is missing: `/r` for reboot, `/s` for shutdown (switch off), `/h` for hibernate, `/l` for logoff or `/g` reboot with restarting running applications

Comment: Knew it was some dumb mistake, lol, but hey, still learning. Thank you very much. It works now, but sadly they 'don't support remote shutdown'. Guess I'll talk to my boss about it.